# Can't find Google fit class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-fit

I'm trying to copy the official Google Fit sample from here [Setup and Sensors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwaQaWGLlTo#t=178). I'm having problems with the `DataSourceListener`. When I try to add that class in AndroidStudio it doesn't seem to find it, the class doesn't seem to exist...

Comment: whats the error message???

Comment: AndroidStudio simply don't recognize DataSourceListener as part of any library and suggests to create the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API has changed slightly since that video was released.  See the [`SensorApi` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/SensorsApi.html) for more details.  The `DataSourceListener` has been replaced by the `OnDataPointListener` which is used in a call to `SensorApi.add(GoogleApiClient, SensorRequest, OnDataPointListener)`.